# GridView Row Update

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview, try-catch

```
if (((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text == "Insert")
        {
            VendorProperties VP = new VendorProperties();
            VP.VendorName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
           try
            {
                VP.ABN = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.ToString());
            }
            catch 
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Please Enter a Number for ABN";

            }
                VP.VendorAddress1 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.VendorAddress2 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.VendorAddress3 = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.State = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.PostCode= ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.ContractorVendorContactName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[10].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            VP.Phone = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[11].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            DropDownList DR = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[12].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            VP.EmailAddressID= Convert.ToInt32(DR.SelectedValue.ToString());
            PinDicDAO.InsertVendor(VP);
        }
```

Above is my code for inserting a record for database through gridview row updating event. the item "VP.ABN"(which inside try catch) is a integer and user should enter an integer.if user enter a string for ABN i need to stop the record inserting to database and just print the message "Please Enter a Number for ABN".in this code even the user enter a string it display the message and still record is inserted to the database as ABN value is 0. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use try catch in this manner.
You want to validate the text box the you can use a regex expression. I am not too familiar with them but the following link should help. [No Validation](http://onetidbit.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/14/)  Here is the [msdn source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx) if you need more help with that.
I think that this should solve your problem if I understood your problem correctly.